# JQuery hiding/showing closest divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on a certain icon, I want to hide/show relevant divs that are appropriate upon that action.

This is the JQuery I use:

```
$('.aTask').on('click','.descHide',function(){
    $(this).closest('.taskDesc').hide();
    $(this).closest('.descShow').show();
    $(this).closest('.descHide').hide();
});

$('aTask').on('click','.descShow',function(){
    $(this).closest('.taskDesc').show();
    $(this).closest('.descShow').hide();
    $(this).closest('.descHide').show();
});

$('#showTasks').on('click','.delete',function(){
    $(this).closest('.aTask').remove();
});
```

But the intended actions do not happen as can be shown in this [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsrkfagr/11/). Where I would click on the minus sign a plus sign should appear and the text below should either disappear or appear.

Comment: Seems like there are multiple elements with the same ID in your HTML; IDs are supposed to be unique, else there can be some weird outcomes. descHide, editTask, deleteTask, descShow all need to be class names because they appear multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.parent().find(...)` instead of `.closest(...)`. Also, `id`s must be unique.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/tsrkfagr/14/)

```
$('.aTask').on('click', '.descHide', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.taskDesc').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.descShow').show();
    $(this).parent().find('.descHide').hide();
});

// you had a typo here $('aTask')
$('.aTask').on('click', '.descShow', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.taskDesc').show();
    $(this).parent().find('.descShow').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.descHide').show();
});

$('#showTasks').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('.aTask').remove();
});
```